How to prove that a quotient function is constant?
Let $w_1,w_2\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ be two functions with $w_1,w_2>0$ and $\dfrac{w_2}{w_1},\dfrac{w_1}{w_2}\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded domain (i.e. open and connected).
We know that $\dfrac{\nabla w_1}{w_1}=\dfrac{\nabla w_2}{w_2}$. How can we show that $\dfrac{w_2}{w_1}\equiv$ constant? I see it in many articles used in that hypotheses.
Warning: Do not try to use this formula:
$$\nabla\frac{w_1}{w_2}=\frac{w_1\nabla w_2-w_2\nabla w_1}{w_2^2}
=\frac{w_1}{w_2}\Big(\frac{\nabla w_2}{w_2}-\frac{\nabla w_1}{w_1}\Big)=0.$$
It is not true because the RHS is not in $L^1$. See here the counterexample of daw:Weak derivative of a quotient.
I also tried to use ACL, but it didn't work because the quotinent of two absolutely continuos function need not be absolutely continuous unless the domain is compact...

The argument may be: $\frac{ \nabla w_1}{w_1}$ is the weak derivative of $\log(w_1)$. Hence the assumptions imply $\nabla \log(w_1) = \nabla\log(w_2)$, then $\log(w_1) -\log(w_2)=const$. Not sure how to make this rigorous.
